# perl regular expression, matching space with digit 1-12

Tags: html, regex, perl

i was trying to grab some data from a horsing data site
http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?horseno=P278

basically i wget the above URl and loop thru each line of the HTML source code and check if the line match regular expression, if it does, i grab some data and store it in a variable

example of the source (it should be in line 384-386):

```
<td class=htable_eng_text align=center>
2      
</td>
```

I was trying to match the digit "2" but i failed

i did something like this:

```
if ($line =~ /\s+([1-12])\s+/) {
#if match, then stored $1 in a variable
}
```

Here's my questions:
not sure if i should add \s+ at the end and
not sure if i could do ([1-12]) as the digit i want to grab in a range of 1-12 (i also try (\d||11||12)) but failed)...

i m new to perl and hope someone could help.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using `HTML::TableExtract` as @Sobrique recommended. Without knowing what information you want, I guessed at the `Race Index` and `Draw` columns.

You can change the columns retrieved using the `headers` parameter of the `HTML::TableExtract->new` call, for instance `[ qw/ Index Dr Jockey Class Course / ]`, but you would have to change the `print` loop to display them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $url = 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?horseno=P278';
my $html = get $url;

my $extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(
    headers => [ qw/ Index Dr /],
);
$extract->parse($html);

my $table = $extract->first_table_found;

print "Race\n";
print "Index Draw\n";

for my $row ($table->rows) {
  my ($index, $dr) = @$row;

  if ( $dr ) {
    $dr =~ s/\s+//g;
    printf "%-5s %-s\n", $index, $dr;
  }
  else {
    print $index, "\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Race
Index Draw
 14/15 Season
390   4
334   9
273   3
207   2
156   7
129   11
098   10
009   10
 13/14 Season
682   12
637   8
596   8
570   6
452   5
372   4
332   3
272   6
218   5
144   9
098   12
033   10
 12/13 Season
728   1
598   9
```

Answer (score 2):

To check range from numeric `1-12` you can use this regex:

```
/\b([1-9]|1[0-2])\b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex to parse HTML. See:[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You should *REALLY* consider using an HTML parser instead. Because in your case, you're manipulating a table, you can use [`HTML::TableExtract`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm). This will turn your table into a nice friendly Perl data structure, and your code will be less brittle.

```
 use HTML::TableExtract;
 $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(Date Price Cost)] );
 $te->parse($html_string);

 # Examine all matching tables
 foreach $ts ($te->tables) {
   print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
   foreach $row ($ts->rows) {
      print join(',', @$row), "\n";
   }
 }
```